# How to use SGI Ropes with Windows Visual Studio 8.0?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, string, stl

Good afternoon, We are building a prototype of a deduplication program with C++ on Windows and Linux. Yesterday, we posted a question on Stack Overflow about how to avoid the STL `string` deep copying when we store a `std::string` version of a record to deduped in the `std::string* StringArray`, STL makes a deep copy of the `string` and `malloc`s a new buffer of at least 160,000,000 bytes. We quickly run out of heap memory and get a `std::bad_alloc` exception

The Stack Overflow experts who answered out question recommending using a better string class such as SGI's Ropes becuases Ropes is buit especially for handling very large strings. So we downloaded a version of SGI's ropes.c and rope.h. However, we could not compile ropes.c and ropes.h on Windows Visual Studio 2008. Also, we couldn't find any examples of how to use the SGI C++ Ropes interface.

So we downloaded a Better String Library by Paul Hsieh. we modified our STL source code to use the `bstring` class implemnted in a Better String Libary. Here is an excerpt of our code:

```
std::vector< bstring > BStringVector;

bstring b = bfromcstr(curr.getPtr());
char* const resultptr = (curr.getPtr() + n);
resultptr[STRING_SIZE] = '\x0';

BStringVector.push_back(b);
curr.mPtr = (char*)bstr2cstr(BStringVector.back(),' ');

std::multiset<Range>::iterator miter = ranges_type.lower_bound(Range(n));
(*miter).mPtr = curr.mPtr;

free (b);
return (char*)(resultptr);
```

This new code generates fewer `std::bad_alloc` exceptions than the STL `string` class, But we know Ropes is the best class for handling very large strings. So we need to know how to use the SGI source on Windows Visual Studio 2008. There are a lot of SGI specific header files in the Ropes code. What are the corresponding Windows Visual Studio 2008 C++ header file?

Also, after reading the Ropes documentation we are still not 90% positive about how to convert the null-terminated contents of a C/C++ `char*` pointer to a Ropes object. In addition, how do we `push_back` a Ropes object onto a STL container such as `vector`? Finally, how do we retrieve the Ropes object from the STL `vector` container? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download only the two implementation files? I doubt that this would work as they most likely rely on other files that are part of the SGI STL implementation. That would explain why you can't build them...

The easiest way to get at the SGI rope implementation might be to use [STLport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/), which is a port and further development of the SGI STL to multiple platforms. I haven't tried using it with VS2008 though, but I'm pretty sure it's supported.

However, you will need to use STLport as a complete STL replacement (which it is) instead of extracting one or two classes and attempt to use that with the STL implementation that ships with VS2008.

That is, unless you fancy rewriting the rope classes to work out of the box with the MS STL, but that doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually we did download the STLport last night but we only extracted 1 or 2 Ropes classes. However, now have you advised us to replace Microsoft STL with complete STLport replacemnt we have to build a new VisualStudio C++ project. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know where we can find some good documentation on how to use the Ropes Class? We haven't found much documentation about ROpes. Are there any Ropes mailing list? Thank you,

Comment: Here is a link to some good Ropes documentation,     < http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html.> Thank you.